# Subclass edit control without ruining copy/paste

Tags: c, winapi, virtual-keyboard, editcontrol

I want to create an edit control where users can only type in floating point numbers, but I want to also be able to copy/paste/cut text in this edit. So I subclassed an edit control with the following window procedure:

```cpp
LRESULT CALLBACK FloatTextboxWindowProc(HWND windowHandle, UINT msg, WPARAM wparam, LPARAM lparam, UINT_PTR subclassId, DWORD_PTR refData)
{
    switch (msg)
    {
        case WM_CHAR:
            // If the character isn't a digit or a dot, rejecting it.
            if (!(('0' <= wparam && wparam <= '9') || 
                wparam == '.' || wparam == VK_RETURN || wparam == VK_DELETE || wparam == VK_BACK))
            {
                return 0;
            }
            else if (wparam == '.') // If the digit is a dot, we want to check if there already is one.
            {
                TCHAR buffer[16];
                SendMessage(windowHandle, WM_GETTEXT, 16, (LPARAM)buffer);

                // _tcschr finds the first occurence of a character and returns NULL if it wasn't found. Rejecting this input if it found a dot.
                if (_tcschr(buffer, TEXT('.')) != NULL)
                {
                    return 0;
                }
            }

        default:
            return DefSubclassProc(windowHandle, msg, wparam, lparam);
    }
}
```

This works, aside from the fact that copy/paste/cut operations are blocked. Nothing happens when I try to do them.

This is confusing to me, because Microsoft says these operations are handled by `WM_COPY`, `WM_PASTE`, and `WM_CUT` messages, which I'm not even overriding. But I tested and found that when I type <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl+V</kbd>, and <kbd>Ctrl+X</kbd> into the edit, it fires a `WM_CHAR` message with the key codes `VK_CANCEL`, `VK_IME_ON`, and `VK_FINAL` (may be respectively, I don't remember). Which is weird, because none of these keys sound like they represent these inputs, and nowhere on the Internet does anyone say they do.

If I add the condition that these key codes are passed on to `DefSubclassProc()` instead of being rejected, it fixes the problem. But I'm hesitant to just take this fix and move on, because I can't explain why it works, and I don't know what bugs it might introduce, resulting from what these key codes actually mean.

So, why does overriding `WM_CHAR` make copy/paste/cut no longer work? And why do these key codes, which seemingly have nothing to do with these inputs, get associated with them? And how might I allow copy/paste/cut in a less hacky way?

Comment: Don't forget to handle `WM_PASTE` if you want to stop them pasting invalid characters in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per the [Keyboard Input](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/keyboard-input) documentation on MSDN:

> Key strokes are converted into characters by the [`TranslateMessage`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-translatemessage) function, which we first saw in Module 1. This function examines key-down messages and translates them into characters. **For each character that is produced, the `TranslateMessage` function puts a [`WM_CHAR`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/inputdev/wm-char) or [`WM_SYSCHAR`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/menurc/wm-syschar) message on the message queue of the window.** The *wParam* parameter of the message contains the UTF-16 character.
>
> ...
>
> **Some CTRL key combinations are translated into ASCII control characters.** For example, CTRL+A is translated to the ASCII ctrl-A (SOH) character (ASCII value 0x01). For text input, you should generally filter out the control characters. Also, avoid using [`WM_CHAR`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/inputdev/wm-char) to implement keyboard shortcuts. Instead, use [`WM_KEYDOWN`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/inputdev/wm-keydown) messages; or even better, use an accelerator table. Accelerator tables are described in the next topic, [Accelerator Tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/accelerator-tables).

So, what is happening is that [`TranslateMessage()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-translatemessage) in your app's message loop converts `WM_KEYDOWN` messages for <kbd>CTRL-C</kbd>, <kbd>CTRL-V</kbd>, and <kbd>CTRL-X</kbd> sequences into `WM_CHAR` messages carrying the **ASCII control characters** 0x03 (ASCII `ETX`, aka `^C`), 0x16 (ASCII `SYN`, aka `^V`), and 0x18 (ASCII `CAN`, aka `^X`), respectively.

`WM_CHAR` carries *translated character codes*, NOT [*virtual key codes*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/virtual-key-codes), which is why `VK_CANCEL` (0x03), `VK_IME_ON` (0x16), and `VK_FINAL` (0x18) are confusing you.  Virtual key codes are not used in `WM_CHAR`.  The reason why `VK_RETURN` and `VK_BACK` (but not `VK_DELETE`) "work" in your filtering is because those keys are *translated* into ASCII control characters, per the [Using Keyboard Input](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/using-keyboard-input) documentation:

> A window procedure receives a character message when the [`TranslateMessage`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-translatemessage) function translates a virtual-key code corresponding to a character key. The character messages are [`WM_CHAR`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/wm-char), [`WM_DEADCHAR`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/wm-deadchar), [`WM_SYSCHAR`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/menurc/wm-syschar), and [`WM_SYSDEADCHAR`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/wm-sysdeadchar). A typical window procedure ignores all character messages except `WM_CHAR`. **The `TranslateMessage` function generates a `WM_CHAR` message when the user presses any of the following keys**:
>
> - Any character key
> - **BACKSPACE**
> - **ENTER (carriage return)**
> - ESC
> - SHIFT+ENTER (linefeed)
> - TAB

<kbd>ENTER</kbd> is translated into ASCII control character 0x0D (ASCII `CR`, aka `^M`), which is the same numeric value as `VK_RETURN`.

<kbd>BACKSPACE</kbd> is translated into ASCII control character 0x08 (ASCII `BS`, aka `^H`), which is the same numeric value as `VK_BACK`.

Note that the <kbd>DELETE</kbd> key is not on the list of translated keys, so the standard <kbd>DELETE</kbd> key will not generate a `WM_CHAR` message, as there is no ASCII control character for delete (however, the <kbd>DEL (.)</kbd> key on a numeric keyboard may generate a `WM_CHAR` message carrying `VK_DELETE`. In this case, bit 24 of the `lParam` will be 1).

So, `DefWindowProc()` would translate these special `WM_CHAR` messages for your clipboard operations into `WM_COPY`, `WM_PASTE`, and `WM_CUT` messages, respectively.  However, you are filtering out those messages so they don't reach `DefSubclassProc()`, and thus do not reach `DefWindowProc()`.

So, as you already discovered, you do need to allow those messages to pass through your filtering, eg:

```cpp
LRESULT CALLBACK FloatTextboxWindowProc(HWND windowHandle, UINT msg, WPARAM wparam, LPARAM lparam, UINT_PTR subclassId, DWORD_PTR refData)
{
    if (msg == WM_CHAR)
    {
        // If the character isn't a digit or a dot, rejecting it.
        if (!(
            (wparam >= '0' && wparam <= '9') || 
            wparam == '.' ||
            wparam == VK_RETURN ||
            wparam == VK_DELETE ||
            wparam == VK_BACK ||
            wparam == 0x03 || // CTRL-C
            wparam == 0x16 || // CTRL-V
            wparam == 0x18)   // CTRL-X
        )
        {
            return 0;
        }
        if (wparam == '.') // If the digit is a dot, we want to check if there already is one.
        {
            TCHAR buffer[16];
            SendMessage(windowHandle, WM_GETTEXT, 16, (LPARAM)buffer);

            // _tcschr finds the first occurence of a character and returns NULL if it wasn't found. Rejecting this input if it found a dot.
            if (_tcschr(buffer, TEXT('.')) != NULL)
            {
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }

    return DefSubclassProc(windowHandle, msg, wparam, lparam);
}
```